# How to get a substring from a MYSQL table TEXTFIELD

Tags: mysql

Assume my DB structure is

```
TABLE1 - id, field1
```

and sample entry is

```
1 
<div class="image" data-content="contact"><img style="margin: 0px auto;display: table;" src="LINK" alt="contact" title=""></div>
```

Now i am trying to get this value **LINK** that is under src tag. I tried useing regex, search but none of them are working correctly.

```
 SELECT * 
   FROM TABLE1
  WHERE field1
BETWEEN 'src' AND 'alt';
```

And,

```
SELECT substring_index(substring_index(field1, 'src=', -1),
                       'alt', 1)
FROM TABLE1
```

Comment: What is the  mysql version ?

Comment: Current version i am testing on is 5.7.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below command

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@str, CHARINDEX('src', @str)+5
, (CHARINDEX('alt',@str)+5) - (CHARINDEX('src', @str) + Len('alt'))-9)
from TABLE1
```

Comment: its not SQL, my bad. Sorry.

Comment: Voila! Using `LOCATE()` instead of `CHARINDEX` worked. And had to remove `Len()`. Thanks!